# Using Artisan console to dispatch a queue job

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan, laravel-10

I am currently working on a Laravel project that imports data from an API into my database. I am using a queue job to fetch the user data from the API and update the data in my database. And I am using the Artisan console to dispatch the job.

Now, my problem is it won't dispatch the job when I input the command in my terminal.

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Jobs\UpdateUser;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class UpdateApiData extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'update:api-data';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Import newly updated data from the API';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        UpdateUser::dispatch(new UpdateUser());
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Services\ApiService;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Models\User;

class UpdateUser implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        Log::info("A dispatch is done");
        $Users = app(ApiService::class)->getUsers()->where("updated_at", "=", "2023-10-20 15:28:31");

        DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                Log::info($User);
                $result = User::updateOrCreate(
                    [
                        'email' => $user['email'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'first_name' => $user['fname'],
                        'last_name' => $user['lname'],
                        'email' => $user['email'],
                    ]
                );
            }
            Log::info("User update or create result: " . json_encode($result));
            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            Log::error($e->getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

I tried the command, but it won't dispatch the job.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you're dispatching the job with itself. When you call `UpdateUser::dispatch(new UpdateUser());`, you're essentially trying to dispatch an instance of the job within the job.

You should dispatch the job without passing an instance of itself. You can modify your UpdateApiData command like this:

```php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Jobs\UpdateUser;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class UpdateApiData extends Command
{
    // ...


    public function handle()
    {
        UpdateUser::dispatch();
    }
}
```

Now, when you run `php artisan update:api-data`, it should dispatch the `UpdateUser` job correctly.

Additionally, make sure that your queue worker is running. You can start the queue worker by running:

```bash
php artisan queue:work
```

Comment: There are no arguments to the job constructor, so whatever is passed to the `dispatch()` method is ignored. The changes you've suggested will make no difference.

Comment: I am quite new to Laravel queue job. Can you give me an idea of what arguments to put in the job constructor?